# Arguments and techniques to ask for more salary by mail

Tags: hiring-process, salary, negotiation

I had attended an interview, say, in company A and after some negotiation they offered me a good figure.

After this I have attended interview in say company B where they have offered more than company A but I more interested to work for company A. Now how do I convey them that I want more salary than the company B is offering me?

It would be great if you arguments and tips about how to communicate this to HR.

Comment: Hi and welcome to [workplace.se]. I took the liberty of editing your question a bit with regards to language and structure. I also re-focussed it away from asking for a mail template, towards the techniques used to write such an email. If you disagree with my [edit], please let me know or feel free to roll it back or [edit] the question some more.

Comment: Why are you doing this by mail? That would seem to be a fantastically inefficient way of negotiating in the 21st century.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there humorous, less-confrontational ways to negotiate a starting salary?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/are-there-humorous-less-confrontational-ways-to-negotiate-a-starting-salary)

Answer (score 3):

> Now how do I convey them that I want more salary than the company B is
>   offering me?

"Dear Ms Company-A decision-maker,

While you have offered me a good salary, I've gotten better offers from other companies. Still, I'd really like to work at Company A. Can you offer more?"

(You might decide to state outright how much Company B is offering.)

Before doing this, make sure you are clear in your own mind what your decision will be no matter what the response from Company A:

- No we cannot offer more, our current offer is our best offer. Take it or leave it.
- What other offers do you have?
- How much more do you want?
- We can offer X more, but that's all.
- Never mind. Our offer is withdrawn. Goodbye.

Unless you have something that makes you exceptional, and far more highly valued than other candidates, most companies don't want to get into a bidding war. So make sure you aren't stringing them along - be ready to decide and live with your decision.

Note: I always suggest you do this sort of thing either in person, or at least by phone - not by mail. That way, you can gauge their reaction and formulate your response better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at both offers in terms of "Total Compensation."

Assign monetary values to the employee benefits:  Health Insurance, paid training, paid time off, etc.

One of those benefits is career advancement.  If you are a software developer, it is probably worth more to make $100K / year at Google or Intuit rather than making $120K / year at "Obscure Tech, Inc.," especially early in your career.

If you're over 50, the difference in retirement packages starts being pretty important.

Pick the one that has the most value *to you.*  Trying to "cherry pick" the best of both offers and get one company to give you that is likely going to put you back in job search mode.

Comment: Well, I'm taking a step back and asking the OP to consider *IF* he should be asking the question, not how.  If you say I'm expanding the scope, then I plead guilty.