# On sites like Monster is the salary final or can it be increased?

Tags: job-search, salary

Say I see a job opening I like on Monster that says up to 35k salary. Say I wouldnt accept less then 40k for my salary.

Is there a point in submitting my resume or is there max written salary non-negotiable?

Perhaps they are just writing an average? Does it depend if they write from $x - $y?

Comment: If you do apply you could probably mention your minimum value in the cover letter. That way you don't waste anyone's time (if they call you, they must be willing to at least consider it) - see e.g. here http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/how-to-respond-to-a-direct-ask-of-salary-earned-and-expectations

Comment: Everything is negotiable and it would not be in the company's interest to advertise a truly fixed "maximum" salary. The intent of such a number is just a rough indication of what they're expecting. $5K more than what they "say" is the maximum is likely within reach of negotiation if you're a good fit and compare favorably to the competition.

Comment: Not on monster on those sort of lower tier sites your not getting the sort of job where there is much scope for this.

Answer (score 2):

Strange things can happen. In the process of accepting a firm offer listed on the website and told during the interview process it was "very" firm, I asked to have my evaluation time period shortened (Which is when I would be eligible for a raise.), so they decided to just increase the salary.

Find out if you really want this job. Review everything in the compensation package. You may be able to get more paid holidays, flexible scheduling, etc. or they may just offer more.

I don't recommend going into this process thinking you can just ask for a larger salary at a later point unless you are really basing it on other assumptions like you assumed it included a 401k or other retirement plan. Since it does not, you would need a larger salary to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can ever tell for sure... what you can do is apply and see whether you manage to negotiate better conditions.

At worst, it may turn out to be a waste of time. At best, you may manage to get something better.

Answer (score -5):

I would take that figure literally, maybe as a stretch for the most superb candidates, so there is no point in sending in your résumé.

Comment: Nonsense. Those are almost always a target pay based on a budget and not a hard cap on salary. Employers will almost always pay more for the right candidate especially if the difference is within reason.