# Expected remuneration, after re-applying for the same job they re-advertised?

Tags: salary, salaried-pay, salary-review

I live in the UK and it is hard to get a job because there's very few vacancies and too many unemployed. I have PhD in Petroleum Engineering and 4 years work experience.
When they asked me first about expected remuneration I put a number within the salary range they advertised in the lower end and I added it is negotiable. BUT they RE-advertised the job again. I RE-applied and they sent me the same question again "expected remuneration".
What should I reply to this question, and what should I reply to my current remuneration knowing that I am not working and a full time mom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to respond to a direct ask of salary earned and expectations?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/how-to-respond-to-a-direct-ask-of-salary-earned-and-expectations)

Comment: also: [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/896/168)

Comment: @gnat, thank you for your commnet but no , it does not. Because I already replied to their email and they re-advertised the job again and i re-applied and they asked me the same question. So, I cannot answer with the same answer

Comment: @Zena - Why can't you provide the same response?  You are making a potential incorrect assumption that the position you applied to wasn't filled and this is simply a different position.  I would imagine it would be typically to have more than a single PhD on staff in the petroleum industry.  There is no reason you cannot provide the same response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume the company readvertised the job because either they did not get (enough) quality candidates, or they prepaid for several postings. If so, you were either rejected, or placed in a long list of candidates and the company is slow. And then,  you were asked about remuneration again because no one noticed you applied twice. Just answer the same so you don't appear unconfident of confused.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be harsh, but they looked at what you said, and they didn't think they were going to get good value for the money.

They may be wrong, of course, but that doesn't matter.

It's really up to you to decide if you're willing to work for less. Nobody here is going to have a great understanding of the job market you're in, and your personal situation.

By they way, there is a slim chance they are a bit more desperate to fill the role now, but they also know that you may be a bit more desperate too, so it kind of cancels each other out.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty, but what should I reply this time?

Comment: It's up to you to determine what figure to give them. If unemployment is high and you need the job, maybe decrease it by a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against giving out this detail. You do not need to tell them what you earn. You could brush it off with a remark like "I don't want to tell you so early on in the recruitment process; it could influence the negotiation".

Comment: This is the correct answer in general, but as Zena already gave a number the first time they applied, it's not really going to work here.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Maybe, maybe not. But if they're asking a second time, it could be safe to assume they're trying to elicit the information a second time. Why, I don't know. Maybe they forgot, it's a different manager this time, etc etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, can I use it for both current and expected remuneration ?