# How To Answer the Infamous Salary Questions

Tags: interviewing, salary, negotiation, compensation

It seems that almost every employer I've interviewed with has asked me the following 2 questions:

- What is your current salary?
- What compensation are you looking for?

A potential strategy might be to answer one of those questions and not the other. For example, not telling them what compensation I'm looking for could leave their offer range more open than accidentally low-balling myself. They could then base the compensation off of the info provided as to what I'm currently making.

On the other hand, I could say that I'm not comfortable telling them what I'm currently making. Then, I can specify what I'm looking for without limiting myself to an increase based off my current salary.

How should I answer (or not answer) these two questions based on the fact that I believe based on my salary research that I am underpaid at my current company?

Comment: How much experience do you have with your position within your industry? This would play a huge role in knowing what makes for a good salary, and the interviewer should know this.

Comment: Another related Q&A... this one really gets asked a lot http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183/does-the-first-person-to-mention-a-number-in-a-salary-negotiation-lose

Comment: I don't really understand this question. Why not just answer honestly, **after doing your homework.** If you're questioned further, be prepared to back up your answers.

Comment: @comeAndGo Mentioning your current salary can significantly affect the offer they make, but doing so is usually expected. Mentioning an expected salary more often than not will affect their offer, regardless of whether it's higher or lower than what they planned to offer, and, in the worst case, might completely take you out of the running for the position.

Comment: @Dukeling - But they're asking you. You need to have the right answers and talk straight - not decline to answer or dodge around. Nobody wants to hire someone who is evasive or tries to move the goalposts. That's why you need to do your homework. State what you made, and state what you think you're worth for the job on the table, based on market price in the industry, location, etc. If they lowball you, then you're involved in negotiation - the normal course of affairs.

Comment: @comeAndGo I (and I assume you as well) don't value money too much and am perhaps too honest for my own good, so I don't personally find this question particularly useful. But not everyone are on the same page regarding this - wanting to get paid as much as possible is logical, and there's certainly a lot of greed, playing games, manipulation and "white" lies in the world we live in, even if we choose not to be a part of it (which often results in it negatively affecting us).

Comment: @Dukeling - could be... I like to code... :) Still, I think what I said holds true. Every job I've landed (and there have been quite a few) was because they sensed I wouldn't bs them - I have been told this explicitly on several occasions. In technical positions, it's important that non-technical people, who often have a big say in the hiring process, feel you're trustworthy and won't be yanking their chain all the time.

Answer (score 5):

"*I prefer not to discuss my previous salary.*" is the way to answer the first question. What I do make right now has no bearing on my worth beyond what my current employer and I have agreed to. There are more diplomatic ways to say the same thing. The whole point is I am trying to get the best salary for the work the company wants me to do.

"*What is the budget you have for this position?*"* is how I start the actual negotiations into salary. If the interviewer is insistent that I provide the first number, I will. Somewhere toward the high end of the range I am looking for. *Suggested by a friend of mine.

This is the strategy I have used successfully many times in the past. I don't expect it to work for anyone else.

Comment: "I am open to a range. What did you have in mind?" can actually backfire on you in an interview, as some interviewers want to know what you as a candidate expect to get out of their job, involving financial, career, and to a certain extent lifestyle terms. Saying something like that tells them that you aren't certain of a few things about the job or industry.

Comment: Also, an argument can be made that your current salary is in fact relevant to the interview, in that they want to ascertain how much of an incentive they would need to offer to get you hooked on the job. Answering that way comes off as a little stand-offish toward the interviewer.

Comment: The wording can be changed to be more or less friendly, depending on how the conversation has been going so far.

Comment: If you are downvoting, please explain why so I can improve my answer.

Comment: An argument call also be made that the interviewer wants to low-ball your salary.

Comment: I am downvoting this answer: _My current salary is not relevant to these discussions._ is **not** the way to answer this question: Since they asked you, they think it **is** relevant, and by telling them it isn't, you may immediately eliminate yourself from contention because you appear troublesome and potentially insubordinate.

Comment: @comeAndGo So what? Interviews are a two-way process.  [Anyone who's willing to eliminate me from contention because I want to negotiate a better deal is someone I don't want to work for](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2012/01/23/salary-negotiation/).

Comment: @AdamZuckerman I think you're being downvoted because they fundamentally disagree with your advice ... to not get low-balled on salary negotiations.  Oh well.

Comment: While I wouldn't use the exact words "My current salary is not relevant to these discussions", it's 100% the correct sentiment.  It isn't relevant.  All that's relevant is the value of you, in that position, to the company you're interviewing with.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - Maybe you missed the point of my comment: It has nothing to do with compensation: Insistence on dictating their agenda for an interview demonstrates the behavior of a recalcitrant employee. They are the inverviewers; you are the interviewee. You are seeking a job, they are trying to decide if they want to give it to you, and they don't owe it to you. If so, it's up to them to decide what their criteria are for giving you the job, and what questions are relevant to them. They ask the question? Either answer it, or leave.

Comment: @comeAndGo Well, your "point" is horrible, horrible advice.  Great way to spend the whole of your working life as an unappreciated, underpaid, undervalued pissant.  Personally, I prefer jobs worth having, with people worth working for.  And those types of jobs, for those types of people *are* negotiable, so standard negotiation strategies (like having the other people make the first offer) apply.

Comment: @MattBelanger Agreed.  A softer wording, such as "my current salary isn't an indication of what I'd need in order to take a position with someone else" might work better.  What I use, anyway.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - you don't say "it's not relevant" if they think it is relevant. That doesn't require you to take less or get low-balled. There are other ways of working around that. If I got "It's not relevant" as an answer from a candidate on an interview, for **any** interview question, my next question would be: "Do you know how to find the exit?"

Answer (score 5):

I was in the same situation ,I answered both questions and was completely honest  with the prospective employer.

- What is your current salary ?

  xxxxx but this is below industry standard as per research(here us the proof...) and is one of my reasons to be looking for a change.
- What compensation are you looking for ?

  *XXXXX + 25 , because then i'm aligned with the industry levels & will feel incentivised enough to make the switch as it enables me to forget about salary being a worrying factor at the next job

The employer's response at this stage will tell you a lot about whether they are fair towards your situation or are disadvantaging you during negotiations by basing their offer on your already existing low salary (rather than what the industry should pay).

Note that your "research" on what you deserve to be paid need to be solid too !

Answer (score 1):

> How should I answer (or not answer) these two questions based on the
>   fact that I believe based on my salary research that I am underpaid at
>   my current company?

These are both common questions, and while it may be uncomfortable, you do need to be prepared to answer. Declining to answer interview questions is usually a way to miss out on the job.

> What is your current salary?

This one is easy. You tell them your current salary. And you indicate that you feel you are currently underpaid.

> What compensation are you looking for?

This is a question you can handle several ways.

Most times, I've just finessed the question and indicated "I'm open to reasonable offers." But then, I haven't gone into interviews feeling that I was ever significantly underpaid. If you take this route, you have already indicated that you are underpaid and want more, but you are leaving it open for them to decipher what "reasonable" means. Be prepared for pushback. You may still need to give them a number.

Or, you can be bolder. You can just say "I feel that I'm worth X". This puts the onus on you to determine which X is high enough to meet your needs, but not too high so as to be unreasonable for this employer. You are the one who is guessing what "reasonable" means here. If your X is too high, you may be considered too expensive, and thus not be offered the job.

Either way, go into the interview with a very clear idea of the minimum you would need to receive in order to accept this position. Be prepared to be offered a bit less than you might want, while still being at least as much as you need.

Comment: The issue I have with answering "what is your current salary?" is that there are 1000's of variables at play.  For example, my company hasn't given regular raises since the crash, and if I even got "cost of living" raises, I would be making quite a bit more.  There is also a concern that the company could use your current salary to low ball you.

Comment: Stazzere - In my experience, it has been a mixed bag.  Most places will ask what your expectations are, because it defuses the situation a bit.  Head hunters/recruiters tend to ask current salary, but my advice would be to turn it on it's head and say you would want $x.  You aren't refusing to answer the question, but are giving them a number you would be happy with.  Any company that uses current salary for a future offer is probably poorly run.

Answer (score 0):

I would not answer the current salary question, but would be willing to discuss what I would like to make.  I would also not proceed if they couldn't give me a budgeted range as well.  Using this information, I could make a determination whether it is worth it to proceed.

You probably won't low ball yourself, if you do your homework.

The issue by giving your current salary/history is that the company could use that number against you.  In other words, they could not do their own independent analysis of how much the market for a particular job pays and how much the job at hand is worth to the company.  There are many variables at play in a salary.