# Who and when do I ask for the offered salary regarding a position?

Tags: professionalism, salary, recruitment, human-resources

I had a phone interview with a recruiter and he asked me for my desired salary range. After the phone screen he submitted my resume to Company X, and the manager at Company X contacted me later for another phone screen, then asked me for an in house interview. I am meeting Manager X today.

I do not know what is Manager X offering for this job. What is recommended and best to do if I want to know? Do I email the question to the recruiter before I go to the interview or do I wait till I walk in and meet/ask the manager?

Comment: Related (non duplicate): [Does the first person to mention a number in a salary negotiation lose?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/183/16)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat That doesn't seem like a duplicate at all - that question is about finding out whether a company is still interested, this one is before an interview strictly about salary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are you not supposed to ask how much you will be paid in an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/are-you-not-supposed-to-ask-how-much-you-will-be-paid-in-an-interview)

Comment: See also: [Should I ask about salary between first and second interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/61902)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the company extends an offer to you that will include the salary.  You can safely assume that since you have been scheduled for an interview that your expectations are within their acceptable range.  If you find a recruiter who is submitting you for jobs that are underpaying you should find a recruiter that can get you more appropriate positions.

When the offer is extended you should be able to negotiate through whomever it is that extends the offer to you, or they will provide you with a contact to communicate your acceptance through.

Most positions are offered with a range in mind for the salary.  Until they meet the candidates and decide who they want to hire, the actual salary is not set.  And even after the offer is extended you can usually negotiate at least a small increase.

Answer (score 2):

> What is recommended and best to do, do I email the recruiter about the
>   offered salary for this position or do I wait till I walk in to the
>   company?

First, the recruited knows the salary range for the position.  They have to because most candidates will want to know that information before they even speak to someone at the company.

At this point, since you have a face to face with the company, *just ask the hiring manager what the salary range is*.  There is nothing wrong with **getting the information straight from the source**, especially since the recruiter dropped the ball and did not provide this basic information to you.

Comment: In my experience the person interviewing often has no say in, or knowledge of the salary expectations for the position.  Even so until they are ready to make an offer they are not going to give anything more than a broad range that is probably under their actual range.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings  That is odd, typically you interview with the **hiring manager** who has the budget and necessary approvals for said position, and thus would know the salary information.

Comment: I suppose that would depend on the position and the size of the company you are applying to, and if this is a contract, or permanent placement position, and if the recruiter is inhouse or 3rd party.

Answer (score 2):

When working with recruiter you should be able to get the acceptable salary bracket for the position.
Generally, he know this, and should be able to release this information to you.
In this case, issue of salary is closed until the offer is extended and salary can be negotiated

Answer (score 1):

My policy is to be upfront about my needs. Salary would be the main reason I take a job, so salary is what I mention first. If I get an email from a recruiter (or phone call), I consider the job description and reply with something like

> Hi [recruiter], Thank you for your email (or call). I am currently making $X, and I would expect a pay increase to $Y if I were to change jobs. Is this in line with your client's expectations?

If the answer is no, I move on. I like PTO and break rooms, but I work for money, so that's what comes first.

If I am unemployed (I have not been, so this is conjecture), I would likely just ask something like:

> Thank you for your email. What is the salary being offered for this position?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Perhaps leave a comment explaining the issue with my answer?

Comment: Assume that any downvote that is not explained otherwise is simply an indication that they do you agree with your answer.

Comment: Or the answer doesn't add anything not provided by the other answers.

Comment: Yes, likely, but if it requires enriching so it can shine, why not take the time to comment if you've spent the rep to downvote? Oh well.

Comment: because people are lazy by nature.

Comment: If you want to improve your answer then you should do so.  This answer works for me personally, but I can see how some people may disagree with your viewpoint, and care more about PTO, and comfortable working conditions than their salary.