# Company wants to extend offer. Is it a good idea to send current salary and expected salary info over email?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I have been contacted after my second interview that the company received great feedback from the team and that they want to extend offer and want to know when I can start.

Here are some facts about the company:
1. They are a small / mid-sized company but they hire from reputable blue chip companies.
2. They have no clue about my salary level and this is the first time they are asking for it. 
3. There is no salary data on this company so I am finding it difficult to "quote" my salary expectations.

Should I be sending them current and expected salary or one or the other? Should I be asking to discuss over the phone? Any other feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Have they extended an offer? If so, they didn't include salary info?

Comment: No. They would like to extend an offer and want to obtain these datapoints so "they can prepare an offer".

Comment: [Other questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/6059/50318) about salary negotiation suggest not giving previous salary because it is irrelevant to current salary all it does is hand the company a bargaining chip.

Comment: @gtwebb- actually this is a fallacy from the old days.  It's what's called framing.  If they go first and say 120 (you want 160), you have to persuade them up to what you want.  If you go first and say 160 they have to  reason you down.  see here:https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141021190335-1249570-framing-your-message-for-a-successful-negotiation

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager Even if you give them the salary you want I still don't think you should give them your previous salary unless you are happy with something similar.  Also I'm not sure how the linked article relates to initial salary negotiation the article basically outlines presenting multiple choices or changes from the original in the most palatable way.  You are not presenting multiple choices just a desired salary.

Comment: Why did you not ask what their salary range was at the interview?  Or even before the interview?  What if you currently are getting $100k and their range was $50k-60K? Now what?

Comment: Are you asking because you don't want to share your current salary? (Maybe you want/expect a lot more than you currently get.) Are you asking because you want to share, but don't know if you are allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally it's a bad idea to share your current salary. Best option is to tell them how much you want and negotiate from there.

Aim high, but make your judgement call on a reasonable amount that won't put them off altogether. It's a negotiation, you can always settle for less as long as the dialogue continues past that point.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't give them your current or expected salary. Have them make an offer first.**

Companies want to pay you the least amount possible, and companies always ask for the prospective employee to give a number first. This is not a coincidence. Think about it: if you give a number lower than they are expecting, they will happily take it. If you give a higher number than they want, they'll just offer lower. If it's way too high, then they might rescind the offer entirely. This can't benefit you.

Say something like "I'm happy to hear you wish to extend an offer, and I'm really excited at the prospect of working for [company]. However, compensation is about more than just salary, so I don't feel it's appropriate to name a number before seeing the rest of the compensation package. I am confident you will make a fair offer and that we can come to terms. When can I expect to see your offer?"

They might push back. Hold your ground. They don't need a number from you to make an offer.

Comment: I've read a good article on negotiating salary and why you should never give a number first, and suggestions for how to get around their excuses for needing one. I'll look for it after I get off work and edit in a link.

Comment: "Companies want to pay you the least amount possible", I've heard this many times and yet never seen anything to back it up.  Some companies may take that approach and if so they probably handle other things the same, so I wouldn't want to work for them anyway.  Most companies want to pay you fairly because they know that you will either reject the offer or leave soon because you are un-happy.  Having to re-do the hiring process costs more than the salary difference.  Some companies offer and pay on the high end because they want to attract and keep the best people.

Comment: I have even worked at several companies that gave ridiculous percent raises for an individual who for whatever reason was being paid too low.

Comment: @cdkMoose They want to pay the least amount possible while still achieving their hiring goals. If they are willing to pay 100 grand and you offer to work for 50, they will happily pay 50 without an argument. That's what I mean.

Comment: And if their offer is so fair and competitive, then there's no reason they need a number from you before making an offer. :)

Comment: If they are willing to pay 100, they are probably already paying someone that and you will leave when you inevitably find out what the other person makes.  How is that in their best interest?  If you are in s position to negotiate, thru also will have to be competitive with other employers in the area

Comment: @cdkMoose are you claiming that if you ask for 50k when they are prepared to pay 100k that they will still offer 100k? I've never heard of someone being offered a higher salary than what they asked for. Why would they even bother to ask your desired salary in that case?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, that's not it, and I disagree with it, too. Expressing your salary as a range is a good way to get an offer at the lowest end of the range. (I made that mistake in my current job.)

Comment: Well, if you asked for 50 and I was willing to pay 100, i'd start by wondering why you thought you are worth so little.  In any competitive market (one with job opportunities), they need to pay you fairly for internal balance and external competitiveness.  That may not be what you think you are worth though, positively or negatively

Answer (score -2):

Are you asking because you don't want to share your current salary?  (Maybe you want/expect a lot more than you currently get.)
Are you asking because you want to share, but don't know if you are allowed?
 1.  If your current company/employer is private, then the salary information could be considered a "trade secret", "confidential" or at least you don't know that it is "public".  So, you might not legally be able to tell them.  Or you might be able to use that as an excuse to not tell them.
 2.  In particular, if you are looking for a large increase and don't want to anchor them at your current salary:  Salary is only one portion of compensation.  I know people who got HUGE salary increases when leaving one employer with great benefits for one with weaker benefits.  (Benefits are not just financial, as they can include telework, training, work/life balance, guest speakers, conferences, etc.)  There are also geographical differences in salary.
 3.  For the "email" portion.  That is a better question for the "security" group, which would likely tell you not to do that, however, everyone does, even those in "security".
 4.  If you are asking about how to get the best offer:  Most discussions, like many on LinkedIn or Ladders state that you should tell them that you expect a competitive salary and total compensation, based on current market conditions; and that salary amount is between $x and $y, depending on the benefits.  Make $y just a bit higher than what you expect as an "anchor".  They'll likely offer a little less than $x, if both of you have done your homework and know the market.

Comment: I don't think this answers the questions I have raised. I had specific questions about the salary.

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score -4):

I get this is a little out there but this is my idea.

They have a maximum they are willing to pay.
But they want to get you for your minimum.

You want their maximum and it must be more than your minimum.

You don't know their maximum and they don't know you minimum.

They write down their maximum and you write down your minimum.

Your both turn over your numbers.  If their maximum is greater than you minimum then you split the difference.  If their maximum is less than your minimum then no deal.

Comment: That's not how negotiation works in the real world. Moreover, it's not going to work for the situation presented by the question.

Comment: This would be a great answer in a perfect world. Too bad we don't live in that world.