# Can I negotiate job salary after mentioning my desired range over phone with recruiter?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

After a lot of interview rounds and a lengthy process for a tech job I applied, I got a phone call from the recruiter that they'd like to offer me the role.

Over the phone, she asked me they are thinking of offering package of **$(X)k/year** and asked me what figure had I in my mind. I promptly said without thinking that I have in my mind between **$(X + 5)k** and **$(X + 10)k** since I need a job. She promptly said that ok then it'll be **$(X + 5)k**. I haven't yet got any formal offer letter and this was a phone conversation.

My question is **after the recruiter agreeing to the minimum of my specified range, can I negotiate more?**

If yes, when should I do it? Once I'm emailed the offer letter?

Also, I was​ called in to grab some paperwork and one of the papers was the job application form which has a 'desired salary' field. Should I just mention the amount that I want in that field? Also, can I ask anything beyond **$(X + 10)k**, which is the upper limit of the range that I specified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the first person to mention a number in a salary negotiation lose?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183/does-the-first-person-to-mention-a-number-in-a-salary-negotiation-lose)

Comment: Find another job offer that is higher than the asked one.

Comment: This seems to be migrated from the personal finance site .. https://money.stackexchange.com/a/80741/41786

Comment: No, it hasn't been migrated @Fattie , it was cross posted here after someone suggested this might be a better place.

Comment: In any case, to answer the question it's **completely normal to do this**, you simply say "now that we know the details of the role, let's discuss salary..." and go ahead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is after the recruiter agreeing to the minimum of my
>   specified range, can I negotiate more?

Once you tell the recruiter the salary your willing to take, it is risky to go back again and say "no wait, I really meant this.."  You *can* do it, but you are likely not going to get it, or worse they *might* pass on you as a candidate all together.

The long and short of it is you need to **weigh the risk** of asking for another 5K after giving a number you already said you would accept.  I would not recommend doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the recruiter isn't a third party. I meant technical recruiter in the company itself. Can you suggest on that?

Comment: @dm1530 Updated my answer.  Actually made it easier.

Comment: I agree with you, if they proposed the lowest salary in the range it's unlikely they're going to accept the highest and impossible that they accept higher than that. The other risk would be that they withdraw their initial offer.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could see you negotiating for more would be after you're working in the job for several months to a year, but only if there's proper justification for it and assuming your probation period is done. Doing this during your probation period will likely just end with them showing you the door.

For example, you approach your boss after 6-12 months of working at said job and make your case for a higher wage. This doesn't of course mean that you will get your higher wage, and very well could mean your boss says no. But when making your case bring up your work ethic, any special skills you have compared to other employees (additional programming languages you know that may help the company), something you've done for the company to save them money/make customers happier, etc.

It also unfortunately depends on how your boss feels about you, if they disagree with your work ethic for example, and see you as a lazy employee they're less likely to give you a raise, or ask their boss(es) to give you one. If you have good rapport with your boss, it's more likely that they'll entertain the idea at the very least.

Anything you can say that would reflect why you should get a 5k pay increase.

TLDR; Ask boss about pay raise after having the job for 6-12 months, or more.

Comment: This a good after the fact option.