# Approached by a Recruiter

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

This recruiter approached me on LinkedIn.

Naturally, I was delighted.

I received preliminary job details (I have to relocate to another country with different life quality ..., different culture etc.), but I was waiting for the proposed salary, but it was never mentioned.

When I asked about the salary, she said "what's your current earnings in your country"?

I am not really interested in negotiating, and based on my salary, I would get a little more. That's the feeling.

Should I decline such job offers with such thrift?

Comment: Recruiters have a quota they have to fill, or commission to earn. If what you are looking for is outside their range, there is no reason to continue.

Comment: I thought to be approached means I was recommended, and therefore I deserve a decent remuneration.

Comment: Very likely you were approached because some kind of key word search picked your profile  (quite likely among many others).

Comment: @Bonaparte Was it an in-house recruiter (meaning the recruiter is an employee of the company offering the job), or a third-party recruiter? In the former case, your understanding can sometimes be correct. Another employee may have asked the recruiter to consider you for the job opening. In such cases, that employee would have probably asked you first, but it is possible that they somehow "forgot" or deemed it unnecessary.(!?) In the latter case, you are just another "lead" for the recruiter, who is essentially a telemarketer.

Comment: It's pretty common to be asked your current / expected salary before / without being told what they're willing to pay. If you're going to straight-up decline all such offers, you're going to have a hard time. [Does the first person to mention a number in a salary negotiation lose?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183/does-the-first-person-to-mention-a-number-in-a-salary-negotiation-lose)

Answer (score 0):

**It's pretty common to approached out-of-the-blue on LinkedIn.** I've been approached many times by people I've never met and have no connection to whatsoever. Always be **courteous and polite** in any professional setting!

> "what's your current earnings in your country"?

There are several approaches to answer questions like this with widely differing opinions. I have my own personal preferences. In this case, I'd treat it just like you would in an everyday social setting. If an acquaintance (or anybody I don't really know very well) asked me what current earnings were (salary, hourly rate, annual income, whatever), I'd simply reply with something like:

> "Well, the typical salary range of an X [occupation] with Y years of experience in the Z [geographical] area is $A-$B."

No, I don't really think it's anybody's business what I earn, and just because you're dangling a job in my face (out-of-the-blue, remember) doesn't mean you get to know, either.

To answer actually this question (if you even answer it at all), I'd at least **wait for the other person to really get serious about a job offer**, like proposing an interview (even a telephone interview). That shows they want you for your skills, and not based a range of income you fall into.

> I am not really interested in negotiating, and based on my salary, I would get a little more. That's the feeling. Should I decline such job offers with such thrift?

I take this to mean that you think the job likely offers more money. Given the other details you have, decide if it's right for you. Only you and the recruiter can decide whether *this* job is the right one for you. If you aren't interested in negotiating, though, I don't think you're really interested in exploring other opportunities. If that's the case, **don't waste your or the recruiter's time and politely recuse yourself**.

> "...Thanks for engaging with me about this opportunity, but at this time, I'm not interested in pursuing other employment opportunities..."

Comment: We were going to move to the step of taking technical tests during this interview process, but I interrupted her with salary questions. Indeed, I think they are looking for skilled candidates, but being approached means they should provide attractive benefits rather comparing my current benefits with theirs.

Comment: @Bonaparte Comparing to your current benefits may be how they're trying to show their benefits are attractive.